# NextJS document return 404

Tags: javascript, next.js, aws-amplify, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I've deployed a nextJS app and recently I've noticed google search console has started to pick up all urls as 404. When accessing the site you do not face a 404 as the page loads correctly.

Therefore I think I have narrowed this down to the initial document fetch returning 404 and the error html. Which is strange as the dom does not reflect this.

Does anyone know what my be causing this issue? The site is built using `next build && next export`

[image]